# Formik Yup Validation of array of strings not working

Tags: formik, yup

I am using formik validations with Yup. I have created a customize react select component to select multiple options. When the user selects an option, its id will push to an array. This is a required field. So I have used this code to validate it, but the error message will not appear.

```
interest: Yup.array().of(Yup.string().required("This field is required"))
```

Then I tried this one. Then the error message will appear but when I select the options, the error message will not disappear.

```
interest: Yup.array().min(1, "at least 1").required("This field is required")
```

This is initial values:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: { 
          interest:[] 
    }
})
```

Also, I need to set the maximum value is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Formik will add the error to the errors object that you can get from the Formikbag.  If the error is being added to the list then you can choose to show an error message by displaying it in your component.  To my knowledge it won't display the error automatically unless you use the formik ErrorMessage component.

Example: https://formik.org/docs/api/errormessage

Comment: This is a react project and the error message is passed to the component through the props and it is displayed. It is working for strings. `name: Yup.string().required("This field is required")`. this is working properly. The thing is how to use this validation for array